# make: referencing shell variables in sed call

Tags: shell, variables, sed, makefile

I am using make and I'd like to reference a shell variable within sed. However, within the `sed`-call `$$LASTMOD` only expands to `$LASTMOD` but I'd like to see sth like

```
-rw-r--r--    1 weiss    Administ     5752 Apr  1 23:44 src/stata/ini-00.do
```

It works for `echo` but not for `sed`. `.ONESHELL` doesn't seem to work either.

```
.SUFFIXES : .do .tmp

DOFILES = $(shell ls src/stata/*.do | sed 's/.do/.tmp/')

all: $(DOFILES)

.do.tmp: 
    LASTMOD=`ls -l $*`; echo $$LASTMOD; sed -e \
    "s/Last modified:.*/Last modified: $$LASTMOD/g" $*.do > $*.tmp
```

**UPDATE:**

After applying the changes as suggested by @geekosaur, @William Pursell and @eriktous it works like a charm:

```
.SUFFIXES : .do .tmp

DOFILES = $(shell ls src/stata/*.do | sed 's/\.do/\.tmp/')

all: $(DOFILES)

.do.tmp: 
    LASTMOD=`ls -l $<`; \
    sed -e "s, Last modified:.*, Last modified: $$LASTMOD, g" $*.do > $*.tmp
```

Comment: The sed script in the assembly of `DOFILES` is probably not what you intend, although it may work for you right now. The `.` in `.do` is interpreted as a special character. This would change a file named `dodo.do` in `d.tmp.do`.

Comment: You are right thanks... changed that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you actually using double quotes there?  I would expect that behavior from single quotes; but with double quotes, you will get `sed` syntax errors unless you escape the slashes or use different pattern delimiters (I generally use `,` when I know there will be `/` involved, as with pathnames).

```
LASTMOD=$$(ls -l "$*"); \
sed "s,Last modified:.*,Last modified: $$LASTMOD,g" "$*.do" >"$*.tmp"
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work either (and `LASTMOD=$$(ls -l "$*")` is not interpreted as Bash variable).

Comment: Please accept my apologies but you were right. It did not work due to the wrongly specified `LASTMOD`-variable, as pointed out by @William Pursell.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean `ls -l $*`, or did you mean to write `ls -l $<`?  What you are doing looks correct except for that.  (Make will echo the command without expanding $LASTMOD, but sed will do the replacement you desire.)

Comment: Argh, you are right! It's $< not $*. However, I wonder who deserves the bounty? @geekosaur was also right in suggesting `,` instead of `/`. I definitely needed both answers to solve my problem...